# How to manage ASP.NET Core Class Library version in source control ?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

We are creating a new ASP.NET Core project that uses a separate ASP.NET Core Class Library for hosting our classes models. The Class Library generates, at each build,  a NuGet package which we can import in our ASP.NET core Web project with no problem.

However, when I do some modifications in our Class Library, I have to change the version number, so my Web Project can detect changes for my NuGet packet. I perform this automatically with a Gulp task. My question is when working together on this project : if we're both making modifications on the Class Library project and, on our own side, we increment several times the version number of this project, how can we manage to have the correct version number on the remote repository, and therefore the good package for our Web Project ?

Comment: In my opinion it should be job done by your build server. Let 1.0.0.* in your code for instance. You can create a script to run your gulp task on the build server

Comment: I would not do this automatically. A Nuget package is no different than an application in that you have release cycles on it. I would "release" versions of the nuget package based on certain rules, such as end of sprint cycle, and stick to the currently released version of that package for the code that uses it.

Comment: Thanks for your comments ! After a lot of discussion with my team, you are right : we will publish the NuGet package on our server build, and it will increment the version number on the developer demand. But in local ? Can Gulp set the version number as beta during the development ?